# JS int array to MVC3 controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an array of strings in JS. All the members are actually numbers.
My controller has an int[] parameter.

I send it from jquery:

```
$.ajax({url: someUrl, data: {ids : JSON.stringify(id_array) }, ...)
```

and I receive it using

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int[] ids) { ...
```

The parameter doesn't get filled, I've checked, the `Request.Form["ids"]` contains "`[\"25\",\"26\"]"`, the string represention of the JSON array. 
Is there any way to do this automatically **without** a lot of int parsing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried not stringifying the array and letting mvc's default model binding do the magic

```
$.ajax({url: someUrl, data: {ids : id_array }, ...)
```

I'm pretty sure .net MVC will see the array and see it is an array of ints and map it to your array of ints correctly

Comment: yes, Request.Form["ids[]"] will have the value "25,26", int[] still not binding.

Comment: @TDaver you need to set .ajax "traditional" property to true for shallow array serialization to work correctly according to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ as well

Comment: all I was missing was the traditional flag. Thanks

Comment: @Keith.Abramo please include a reference to the  traditional property in your answer.

Answer (score 11):

For MVC3 you need to configure jQuery to use traditional, "shallow" serialisation.. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Client-side AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; //enable "shallow" serialisation globally
$.get("someUrl", {ids : id_array });
```

Action Method:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] ids) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in two different ways

**1. Use $.ajax to post data to your action**

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     url: '/myController/myAction',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     type: 'POST',
>     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>     traditional: true,
>     data: $.toJSON(json),
>     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
>     ...
>     }
> });
> ```

Your action should look like this one

```
public class myController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult myAction(List<int> json)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

**2. Use $.post to post your data**

> ```
> $.post(
>     '/myController/myAction',
>     { json: $.toJSON(products) },
>     function (data) {
>     ...
> });
> ```

In your action you should deserialize JSON string

```
public class myController
    {
    public ActionResult myAction(string json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<int> list = serializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(json);
    }
}
```

You need to download and include jquery.json-2.2.min.js to your code.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/downloads/detail?name=jquery.json-2.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl, 
    data: id_array.map( function(item){ return {name:'ids',value:item}; })
})
```

That is because in order to receive a list on the backend, the data need to be send in the form `ids=3&ids=5&ids=1&ids=7`

---

For IE versions that do not support `.map` use

```
function arrayToParamObject(name,array){
    var obj = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i< len; i++){
        obj.push( {name: name, value: array[i] } );
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and use it

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrl, 
    data: arrayToParamObject('ids', id_array)
})
```